# invalid operands to binary * (have 'double *' and 'double *')

Tags: c, arrays

I have a program that multiplies matrices sequentially in C that I'm trying to finish up. I'm getting the error listed in the title.

Here is the line that is giving me the trouble:

```
C[i,j] = C[i,j] + A[i,k] * B[k,j];
```

A, B, and C are 2-dimensional arrays. They are defined with this code:

```
A = (double **) malloc(sizeof(double *)*n);
for (r = 0; r < n; r++) {
  A[r] = (double *) malloc(sizeof(double)*n);
}
```

The definition of B and C are the same as this. n is an integer value which defines the size of the columns and rows.

I don't know why I'm getting this error. From some of the other questions I've looked at, this error comes up when the types for an operation are incorrect, but I don't understand why that's the case here. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: [Don't cast the result of malloc (and friends)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845).

Comment: Array indexing does not need a comma.

Comment: @Deduplicator This didn't come when I was doing my search. Thank you for pointing it out to me.

Comment: @wildplasser So I should have C[i][k] instead?

Comment: Yes. The comma would be interpreted as the comma-operator, so the array would only by singly indexed, yielding a pointer expression.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no multi-index indexing-operator in C.

What you have is actually single-indexing with an expression which contains the comma-operator.

The comma-operator always returns its second argument.

So, use normal indexing twice instead of trying to cram a second index in there somehow.

```
C[i,j] = C[i,j] + A[i,k] * B[k,j];
```

Is equivalent to:

```
C[j] = C[j] + A[k] * B[j];
```

Not to what you seem to want:

```
C[i][j] = C[i][j] + A[i][k] * B[k][j];
```

As an aside, [Don't cast the result of malloc (and friends)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/605845):

```
A = (double **) malloc(sizeof(double *)*n);
```

should be the less error-prone:

```
A = malloc(n * sizeof *A);
```

Comment: I think I must have copied that over from the algorithm I was looking at. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Yes, those pseudo-code algorithm normally use more mathematical notation. Also, you are a step up from most if you really read such things.

Answer (score 2):

`C[i,j]` is equivalent to `C[j]`. `i,j` in this context is treated as a comma operator whose value is the last expression.

Instead of

```
C[i,j] = C[i,j] + A[i,k] * B[k,j];
```

use

```
C[i][j] += A[i][k] * B[k][j];
```